# Put a integer in a json object in java

Tags: java

I want this `{"code":200}` and try

```
objRes = new JSONObject();
objRes.append("code", 200);
```

but forms `{"code":[200]}` instead `{"code":200}`

Comment: `objRes.("code", 200);` don't you forgot the method name ? the lintax looks odd

Comment: Which of the dozens of JSONObject classes are you using? Which package, which library? Have you read its javadoc? Where is it located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the put method instead :

```
objRes.put("code", 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
JSONObject objRes = new JSONObject ();
objRes.put("code", 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 final JSONObject ref = new JSONObject();
 ref.put("code", 200);
```

The output is `{"code":200}`